# Set request for display encoding page

Tags: javascript, html, request

I have problem with display page.

I access to my page => The text in page will be break font.

But when I using Set Character Encoding extension and select UTF-8 => Text display normal

[image]

=> what is difference between normal and UFT-8 request?
I want to display page with UTF-8 but don't change code => What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> what is difference between normal and UFT-8 request?

You've misinterpreted what is happening. The request is the same in each case. The difference is how the browser is treating the response.

> I want to display page with UTF-8 but don't change code => What should I do?

The short version is:

Computer data is made up of 1s and 0s. There are different ways to represent text by arranging those 1s and 0s. For almost all purposes today, the best choice is UTF-8.

When a server makes an HTTP response, it sends a set of HTTP headers and then an HTTP body.

The headers consist of a bunch of metadata including a header which can describe the character encoding. It is also possible to specify this information using a `<meta>` element in an HTML document, but this plays second fiddle to an HTTP header.

You need to make sure that that header and/or `<meta>` matches the truth about the encoding your document uses.

Essential reading:

- W3C: [Character encodings for beginners](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)
- W3C: [Choosing & applying a character encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings)
- W3C: [Declaring character encodings in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)
- Stackoverflow: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)